# How to controle access to websocket server?

Tags: php, security, websocket

I recently began using WebSockets and I noticed that **anyone** with the link could start listening to my WebSocket server, and I don't want that.
I want to allow **only** my application users to use the WebSocket server.

**My approach:**
I can make my users send me authentication, if it's valid they stay connected or else I disconnect them from the server.
And if they didn't send me anything I disconnect them after a certain period of time.

But since I'm new to WebSockets I wanted to ask if there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'd like to do this because I iterate through my WebSocket clients and I want to minimize the number of clients to improve response time

Comment: It would've been nice if connecting to WebSocket was through Authentication :/

Comment: 1. Don't comment on your own questions.. edit them instead.

Comment: 2. Websocket connections start as HTTP "Upgrade" requests, including cookies and everything. It is better to use pre-connection authentication than post connection authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the messy question, but What do you mean by "pre-connection authentication"? htaccess auth?